# Combinatoric sum

Tags: combinatorics, limits

$$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty }\sum _{k=0}^n\frac{C\left(n,\:k\right)}{k2^n+n}$$

I've tried the Squeeze theorem but it didn't work.

Comment: your question is a bit dry...for example what is $C(x,y)$? Binomial Coefficent?

Comment: @tired Yes, i didn't find another way to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sum_{k=0}^n C(n,k)^2=C(2n,n)\sim 4^n/\sqrt{\pi n}$, (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Series_involving_binomial_coefficients) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas)) we have that
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^n&\frac{C(n,k)}{k2^n+n}\le\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{C(n,k)}{k2^n}\stackrel *\le2^{-n}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k^2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&<2^{-n}\binom{2n}n^{1/2}\frac\pi{\sqrt 6}\sim\frac{2^{-n}2^n\pi}{\sqrt[4]{36\pi n}}\to 0\end{align}$$
where the inequality $(*)$ is an application of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Is there any simpler way to prove this ? I didn't know this approximation.

Comment: It is a consequence of Stirling's. I have proved this in a way as simple as I could. Perhaps there is another simpler way.